# Windows Form application closes when user closes attached console

Tags: c#, winforms, console

I need an Windows Forms application with the below behavior:

1. Work without any console when program is running from explorer (for example).
2. Redirect all text from `Console.WriteLine()` when program is running from a command line (so program must to redirect all output to a parrent console)

For this purpose is suitable the following code:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);

[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    AttachConsole(-1);
    Console.WriteLine("Test1");
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
    Console.WriteLine("WinForms exit");
}
```

But here is one problem: When the form is opened and a user closes the console, then my program automatically closes. I need to leave program running after user closes console. I tried to use `SetConsoleCtrlHandler()` and in the handler call `FreeConsole()` but all the same the program closes after calling handler:

```
static class Program
{
    [DllImport("Kernel32")]
    public static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine Handler, bool Add);

    // A delegate type to be used as the handler routine 
    // for SetConsoleCtrlHandler.
    public delegate bool HandlerRoutine(CtrlTypes CtrlType);

    private static bool ConsoleCtrlCheck(CtrlTypes ctrlType)
    {
        Console.OutputEncoding = Console.OutputEncoding;
        FreeConsole();
        return true;
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool FreeConsole();

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        AttachConsole(-1);
        SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleCtrlCheck, true);
        Console.WriteLine("Test1");
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        Console.WriteLine("WinForms exit");
    }

    // An enumerated type for the control messages
    // sent to the handler routine.
    public enum CtrlTypes
    {
        CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
        CTRL_BREAK_EVENT,
        CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT,
        CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
        CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT
    }
}
```

How to prevent closing Windows Forms application when user closes console?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel thank you for the link! But unfortunately, there just stating the fact that this is not possible...

Comment: If fact is not possible then answer is also same right? May be you should ask another question saying your problem with what you're trying to achieve and you may need to think about really  you need a console?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes, you are right. I'm just unhappy with this fact :) My program really needs only console window and nothing else, so I will have to accept with this fact... Thank you for your participation in my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you could catch the Window Closing Event like

```
    private void winMain_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that in a console window exists such event? Can you give more code? (with subscribing to this event)